# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.uint8") to str

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

when i run this code i get error

```
    import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()

train_images = train_images/255.0
test_images = test_images/255.0

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', "Coat", 'Sandal', 'shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

model = keras.Sequential([

    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
print('Test accuracy : ', test_acc)

prediction = model.predict(test_images)

for i  in range(5):
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(test_images[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel("Actual : " + test_labels[i])
    plt.title("Prediction : ",class_names[np.argmax(prediction[i])])
    plt.show()
```

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dwark/PycharmProjects/test/neural network 01.py", line 33, in 
    plt.xlabel("Actual : " + test_labels[i])
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.uint8") to str**

Comment: plt.xlabel("Actual : " + str(test_labels[i]))

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.uint8") to str

Pretty self explanatory

```
test_labels[i] # is not a string so just change it into one
str(test_labels[i]) # should fix it
```